# Counting sort, why use cumulative

Tags: java, sorting, counting-sort

I went through the code of counting sort in many websites. 
They are using cumulative sum of count and then further array indexing. 
I meant to ask why aren't they using normal array printing:

As if [count of origArray(i) in count(origArray(i))!=0], loop through count(origArray(i)) and print i.

Is this because the main point of using Counting sort is NO COMPARISON, and there is a comparison with 0 in my code.

See this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CountingSort {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        new CountingSort().sort();
    }

    private void sort() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        int max = 0;
        String data = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && line.length() != 0) {
            data += line;
        }
        String[] ip = data.split(" ");
        int[] intArray = new int[ip.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ip.length; i++) {
            intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(ip[i]);
            if (intArray[i] > max)
                max = intArray[i];
        }
        int[] count = new int[max+1];
        Arrays.fill(count, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            ++count[intArray[i]];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (count[i] != 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < count[i]; j++)
                    System.out.print(" " + i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "no comparison" means that keys are not compared to each other to establish their relative order. What do you think is wrong with your code, apart from a little redundancy?

Comment: Nothing wrong, On other sites they used the concept of principal sum, so I thought there might be something wrong with this implementation.

Comment: Could you share a link?

Comment: www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/ ,    www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/countingSort.htm

Comment: `if (count[i] != 0)` is unnecessary, because when `count[i]` is zero the loop to `j < count[i]` will execute zero times.

Comment: Without that condition, printing isn't possible in this algo.

Comment: Of course it is possible - when the count is zero, the second loop wouldn't be entered anyway. Give it a try.

Comment: Okay, I get it,  Thanks!

Comment: So, there is nothing wrong in this right ? O(n+k) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementations at the links that you share do not print `System.out.print(" " + i)` because they consider `i` different from the items being sorted. This would be true if you wanted to sort `char`s, because you would need a cast.

Since you are using integers, there is nothing wrong with your implementation. In fact, you ended up with one of the variations of the algorithm mentioned on Wikipedia:

> If each item to be sorted is itself an integer, and used as key as well, then the second and third loops of counting sort can be combined; in the second loop, instead of computing the position where items with key `i` should be placed in the output, simply append `Count[i]` copies of the number `i` to the output.

Answer (score 3):

In your implementation, you are trying to generate sorted output from your **count** array. It's perfectly fine if you want to make sorted list from array of unsorted integers.

But, now I am going to discuss about a problem scenario where it's not possible to generate output from **count** array.

Suppose we have a list of **Data** containing two field (*categoryID* and *itemName*). We can assume that the field *categoryID* is in range of [0..10]. We want to make a sorted list based on *categoryID* by means of **Counting-Sort Algorithm**. Sample input and output is given bellow:

```html
Unsorted Items -->
2  Computer
5  Shirt
3  Bier
0  Soap
2  Laptop
3  Vodka
0  Lotion
3  Whiskey


Sorted Items -->
0  Soap
0  Lotion
2  Computer
2  Laptop
3  Bier
3  Vodka
3  Whiskey
5  Shirt
```

Now we can easily count the number of items per category. But from this count information, we are not able to generate output containing both *categoryID* and *productName*.

Therefore, Counting sort uses the idea of cumulative sum , which is actually a way to calculate final index in the output array for an item. Here is the solution for this problem.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Data
{
public:
    //let's assume category ID is in range [0..10]
    //Therefore, We can use counting sort for array of Data
    int category;
    string name;
    Data(){}
    Data(int id, string str)
    {
        category = id;
        name = str;
    }
};

vector<Data> Counting_Sort(vector<Data> A)
{
    int k = 10; //maximum category
    vector<int> C(k+1,0);
    for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
    {
        C[ A[i].category ] = C[ A[i].category ] + 1;
    }

    for(int i=1; i<=k; i++)
    {
        C[i] = C[i-1] + C[i];
    }

    vector<Data> B(A.size() + 1);
    for(int i = A.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        B [ C [ A[i].category ] ] = A[i];
        C [ A[i].category ] = C [ A[i].category ] - 1;
    }

    vector<Data> ans(B.begin()+1, B.end());
    return ans;
}

void Show(vector<Data> vals)
{
    for(Data val:vals) cout<<val.category<<"  "<<val.name<<endl;
}

vector<Data> inputData()
{
    int numberOfItems = 8;
    string productNames[] = {"Computer", "Shirt", "Bier", "Soap", 
                             "Laptop", "Vodka", "Lotion", "Whiskey"};
    int categoryID[] = {2,5,3,0,2,3,0,3};
    vector<Data> inData;
    for(int i=0; i<numberOfItems; i++)
    {
        Data data(categoryID[i], productNames[i]);
        inData.push_back(data);
    }
    return inData;
}
int main()
{
    vector<Data> A = inputData();
    cout<<"Unsorted Items --> "<<endl;
    Show(A);
    vector<Data> ans = Counting_Sort(A);
    cout<<"\n\nSorted Items --> "<<endl;
    Show(ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The cumulative sum is to count repetitions: you may have 3 times the value 200 in your array. In this case, `count[200]` will have the value 3. So, You need to print it three times (the last `for` loop in your code).

In sorting algorithms, "comparison" means comparing the values of the arrays to each other. There is no such comparison in this algorithm.

The complexity of this algorithm in O(n), but needs a lot of storage if the values to be sorted may be big.